# Multi-source using DBT

Tags: postgresql, dbt

I'm starting out in the world of dbt, I came across a problem.

I have 2 sources registered in my "profiles.yml", one with data collected from an API and the other with data from my ERP database.

I created a DBT project for each source, however, after processing the API data I need to migrate it to the ERP project, is there any way to do this?

I tried to use dbt-meshify with the command "dbt-meshify connect --project-paths" passing the location of the 2 projects as a parameter, in my ERP project I put a "dependencies.yml" pointing to the API project, but when running the command it does not find dependencies between projects.

Comment: Can you elaborate the relationship between two projects? Are they have the same dataset just different data source, or they share part of the dataset? And what is the functionality you try to achieve with dbt?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am not sure you are using dbt the right way. The whole paradigm is to first bring all your sources in a data warehouse (using tools like airbyte or fivetran for API-based data source) and then do the modelling with dbt. dbt is not an ingestion tool per-se